# Menu lateral com width fixo e content 100%

Tags: html5, css3

Eu estou trabalhando em um projeto, que o meu menu lateral tem 300px e o meu `content` tem 100% relativo com o meu menu.

Eu aplico o seguinte estilo:

```
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 300px; /* Para que fique ao lado do menu */
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Porém quando eu aplico isso ao site, a classe `content` fica maior, e aparece o *scroll* para visualizar o resto. Eu quero que o `content` fique 100%, mas relativo com o menu de 300px.

Segue o link, para vocês verem: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lwLHJ

Comment: Bem-vindo ao site! Você poderia [edit] sua pergunta, selecionando os trechos de código e clicando no botão `{}` do editor para formatá-los adequadamente? Obrigado!

Comment: Talvez seja melhor você parar de usar a palavra "relativo," pois se for assim já esta certo. Você esta simplesmente fazendo o `.content` da largura da janela e movendo ele para direita 300 pixels. Você deveria procurar alguns livros sobre HTML + CSS para estudar primeiro, pois você não tem a menor idéia do que esta fazendo.

Answer (score 3):

No **width** do **.content** use o valor **auto**.

```
width: auto;
```

[Clique aqui e veja o seu código alterado no Codepen.io.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zdFyv)

**Dica**: O ideal seria no lugar da tag **header** você usar a tag **nav** que tem a verdadeira função de delimitar um *menu* no *html5*.

- [nav - HTML 5 - W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp)

Answer (score 0):

No .content você pode adicionar o seguinte:

```
.content {
   width: calc(100% - 300px);
   position: relative;
   margin-left: 300px;
}
```

Não poe o .content como position: absolute, pois caso houver conteúdo, ele não acompanha as dimensões do mesmo.